# How to obtain stabilizer's generators of a QEC code

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

The theory of QEC with stabilizer codes defines an alternative way to represent a quantum state in terms of operators. 
To understand better what I am concerning about, let's consider the 7-qubit Steane code:

$$
\left|0\right\rangle_L \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(\left|0000000\right\rangle + \left|1010101\right\rangle + \left|0110011\right\rangle + \left|1100110\right\rangle + \left|0001111\right\rangle + \left|1011010\right\rangle + \left|0111100\right\rangle + \left|1101001\right\rangle)
$$
$$
\left|1\right\rangle_L \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(\left|1111111\right\rangle + \left|0101010\right\rangle + \left|1001100\right\rangle + \left|0011001\right\rangle + \left|1110000\right\rangle + \left|0100101\right\rangle + \left|1000011\right\rangle + \left|0010110\right\rangle)
$$

Papers and books directly define the relative generators as:

$$
K^1 = IIIXXXX
$$ 
$$
K^2 = XIXIXIX
$$
$$
K^3 = IXXIIXX
$$
$$
K^4 = IIIZZZZ
$$
$$
K^5 = ZIZIZIZ
$$
$$
K^6 = IZZIIZZ
$$
where I is identity matrix and X,Z Pauli's matrices.

Therefore, my questions are: how these generators have been calculated? 
How can I calculate the generators for a generic superposition of n qubits?

Thank you

Comment: I think, we usually guess the generators by(specially in the [CSS case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_code)) by their classical dual, and then find the logical qubits and check whether they are useful or not.

Comment: An algorithm would respect the rules : 
a) $|0_L\rangle$ and $|1_L\rangle$ are eigenvectors of all the generators $K_i$, with eigenvalue $1$
b) For each error operator $E$ (in the $X_i, Y_i, Z_i$), there is at least one generator $K_j$ which anticommutes with it (such as $E|0\rangle$ and $E|1\rangle$ are eigenvectors of $K_j$, with eigenvalue $-1$).
c) For each error operator $E$ (in the $X_i, Y_i, Z_i$), the set of generators ${K_j}$ which anticommutes with $E$ is unique (there is not an other error operator with the same set of generators)

Comment: Now, practically, one may, for instance, try to restrict to generators  build with $I,Z$ or $I,X$.

Comment: This might be a good opportunity to encourage posters to spell out abbreviations (at least once). Abbreviations may not be obvious to readers with a different background.